# Vim register completion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-registers

I would like to have some sort of auto completion for named registers.
If I try to access one (<kbd>"</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> ...) a completion similar to the line completion (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>) should be opened.
Some nice visualization of the unused/free register would be nice too.

Is there a nice solution for this?

Comment: What about `:reg` or `:reg a`?

Comment: It isn't as comfortable as I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooking into the built-in commands (like <kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>) is difficult, because Vim then is in a special sub-mode where it waits for the register name. I use the following <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> mapping (which normally is a no-op) to refresh my memory:

```
" ["x][N]""         List contents of the passed register / [N] named
"                   registers / all registers (that typically contain
"                   pasteable text).
nnoremap <silent> <expr> "" ':<C-u>registers ' . (v:register ==# '"' ? (v:count ? strpart('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 0, v:count1) : '"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*+.') : v:register) . "<CR>"
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently created plugin https://github.com/imomaliev/registers.vim

Install it with your favourite plugin manager(like Plug)

```
Plug 'imomaliev/registers.vim'
```

Аnd after that you can do `<C-x><C-r>` in insert mode and completion menu with registers will be called.